# AWS-SDK for JavaScript, Getting SecretValue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

Basically I have a Lambda function that I'm trying to get some credentials for using Secrets Manager.  I feel like I'm missing something silly here but no matter what I try I either get a timeout or the client block never even runs.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const {
    SecretsManagerClient,
    GetSecretValueCommand
  } = require("@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager");
  const client = new SecretsManagerClient({ region: "us-east-1" });
  const command = new GetSecretValueCommand({
    SecretId: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:my-secret-arn"
  });

  client.send(command).then(
    (data) => {
      console.log("Maybe?");
      console.log(data.SecretString);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
  
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200
  };
  return response;
};
```

Comment: It sounds like you are running the Lambda function from within an VPC, and have deployed it into a subnet without a route to a NAT Gateway. This is the most common reason a Lambda function will timeout when trying to make network calls.

Answer (score 0):

Does your lambda have the appropriate policy in its execution role? The SDK may return you a misleading error (i.e. CredentialsError) when you don't have the right policy in place.